# not able able to create new user even though m giving it new username

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

*** this my User model ***

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique :true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

`this is my auth js`

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPass,
    });

    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//LOGIN
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    !user && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    !validated && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
    res.status(200).json(others);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

*** m trying to create new user , m using thunder Client , post request ***

*** json that i entered in body ***

```
{
  "username" : "krish",
  "email" : "krish@gmail",
  "password" : "password"
}
```

*** response that m getting is given below , after creation of first user  m not able to create other user even though m proving unique username and email ***

```
 {
      "index": 0,
      "code": 11000,
      "keyPattern": {
        "Username": 1
      },
      "keyValue": {
        "Username": null
      }
    }
```

*** my index.js ***

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

app.listen("3000", () => {
  console.log("Backend is working at 3000");
});
```

Comment: provide the error you are getting and also where? Do some console.log for req.body and user object after you save.

Comment: i have already provided error  as u can see in my auth.js , in try catch i have returned err like this ` const user = await newUser.save();
                                       res.status(200).json(user);
                                          } catch (err) {
                                              res.status(500).json(err);  } `

Answer (score 1):

i check my backend code nothing was wrong , neither i was giving the same username , the culprit was mongoDb  ,all u have to do is go to your data collection , then to index and the remove the index and your are good to go restart your app and then  it will work